# Is is possible to store a Firestore field into a Swift file, and use the Swift file in a TableViewController?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to extract a Firestore field (from a document), store it in a Swift file, and then use the value to create cells in a TableViewController?

The following is stored in my Firestore database:

```
users {
    userid {
        "level":0
        "subjects":[""]
        }
    }
```

Can I somehow store 'subjects' into a Swift file (blank), and use this variable to make Table View cells (using rows)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are trying to do is query `users` for a specific user's "subjects" and store it in an array then this should work.

```
var db = Firestore.firestore()

let usersRef = db.collection("users").document(userid)

usersRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {

        let subjects = document.data()!["subjects"]

    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

That subjects array can be used for your table view.

Comment: I can't exactly place `subjects` into `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 0 }`; is there any way that I can do that?

Comment: You would return `subjects.count` and not `0`. If you are having trouble accessing the variable `subjects` in `numberOfRowsInSection` then make sure it is declared on the class level (ie before `viewDidLoad`) and then in `getDocument` just set `subjects` instead of declaring it.